# Image preview using Dropzone extending File type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dropzone.js

Would like to preview an image before uploading using dropzone. I am trying to map the images by calling `file.preview` but it does not exist on type File. Dropzone extends the file type with a `preview?: string`. My question is how do I access the extended type? How do I show an image with the URL.createObjectURL I'm using. I am new to TypeScript and cannot wrap my head around the problem. Any help is appreciated.

- I have tried creating a custom interface, importing it and assigning it to files: Pic[] to no success. Complains that the properties do not exist on the accepted files. I understand that. Perhaps I have to declare what is what in the function? No idea.

```
export interface Pic {
  picId: string
  name: string
  preview: string
}
```

- I have Object.assigned a preview URL within the onDrop function. It carries over but still cannot access it through files.preview.
- I tried using a constructor to get the extended type but get completely lost in what I'm trying to achieve.

```
import * as React from "react"
import styles from "../../styles.scss"
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone"

class ImageUpload extends React.Component {
  state = {
    files: []
  }

  handleOnDrop = (files: File[]) => {
    files.map(file => Object.assign(file, {
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
    }))
    this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, ...files] })
    console.log(files)
  }

  render() {
    const files = this.state.files.map((file: File) => (
      console.log(file),
      (
        <li key={file.name}>
          {file.preview}
        </li>
      )
    ))

    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <h2>Upload images</h2>
        </div>
        <Dropzone onDrop={this.handleOnDrop} accept="image/*" />
        <ul>{files}</ul>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default ImageUpload
```

Expected results: file.preview URL works and I can use it as a background image.
Actual results: file.preview does not exist on type File.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how do I access the extended type?

By importing the interface from the type definitions:

`import Dropzone, { FileWithPreview } from "react-dropzone"`

Aside of that question. The Array.map function returns a new Array. Currently you're only mapping the files array, but you're not doing anything with the new Array. You would want to use that new array to set your state with:

```
const filesWithPreviews: FileWithPreview[] = files.map(
  // Add the preview property to each file element
);

this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, ...filesWithPreviews] });
```

And seeing as you're new to TypeScript. You should set an interface to match your state.

```
interface IState {
  files: FileWithPreview[];
}

class ImageUpload extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
}
```

This way TypeScript lets you know that you're trying to store an incorrect type of an element to the state which you'd like (like that is happening right now in your dropHandle function). And you wouldn't have to explicitly say that a file is a `File` in your render function, when mapping the array.

Comment: I ended up mimiccing what I saw in the dropzone @type. I created `interface ImageFile extends file { preview?: string }` and changing the arguments to `ImageFile`. When I extended the interface I was given many problems that things did not exist on type. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I get "Module '"react-dropzone"' has no exported member 'FileWithPreview'" for React Dropzone 14.2.3.

Comment: Going through the source code of react-dropzone, it looks like the FileWithPreview type was dropped after version 6.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, @Alserda's answer is no longer fully applicable because the `FileWithPreview` export appears to have been dropped from React Dropzone after version 6 (circa 2018).

I ended up using the suggestion in @Prozak's reply to that answer, which was to recreate the type (actually an interface) in my own code, like so:

```js
export interface FileWithPreview extends File {
  preview?: string;
}
```

(This is exactly how it was defined in React Dropzone itself, pre-version 7.)

Once you have the interface, you can plug it into your own code as shown in @Alserda's answer.